# Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. in AJAX response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

My Ajax request code:

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    var $form = $(document).find('#name-form');
    var $display = $(document).find('#display');
    $form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $form.find('#name').val();
        var surname = $form.find('#surname').val();
        var patronymic = $form.find('#patronymic').val();
        var year = $form.find('#year').val();
        var request = $.ajax({
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            method: 'get',
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback",
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8885/search?app=potato',
            data : {
                name: name,
                surname: surname,
                patronymic: patronymic,
                year: year,
            }
        });
     function localJsonpCallback(json) {
            if (!json.Error) {
                $('#display').submit();
            }
            else {
                $('#display').show();
                alert(json.Message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This code sends the request, this is for sure. But when it gets the JSON, console writes an error `Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.` All I need is to simply show this json or it's content in a div.

The response JSON is:

```
{
  "Report": "http://127.0.0.1:8099/chicken/eggs.html",
  "Exist": true
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please show the code that generates the JSON.

Comment: please show the values for your sent data.

Comment: JSON is generated by an app, Sikuli, after it finishes it's job. In the question I show what it returns (copied from postman). RAW response: `{"Report": "http://127.0.0.1:8099/chicken/eggs.html", "Exist": true}`. Do you think JSON is somehow messed up? It is valid though, I suppose.

Comment: Values come from a form, all just text and in a year it's numbers like 1990. The app (Sikuli) that is triggered by this request works perfecty, inserting everything I write in all these 4 forms.

Comment: In the console I can see the JSON, but it also writes this arror. So it looks like everything is ok except parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You're telling jQuery that you want JSONP but the server is returning JSON.

Due to how jQuery handles JSONP, the normal JSON is treated as though it's javascript and so the error you're getting is actually a syntax error thrown by the browser's javascript interpreter.

Comment: Yes, I use JSONP to avoid cross-domain error. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: @SamBronson If you or someone associated with you are creating the server-side code, then you need to allow it to recognize JSONP requests and return JSONP responses. Simply requesting JSONP from a server that doesn't support it won't work.

Comment: Generally, to use data from another server you need to show that the server agreed to your use. One way is for the server to allow JSONP requests. Since it's not returning JSONP formatted data, this isn't going to work. To get normal JSON to work, you'd need to enable CORS on the server or serve the page from the same protocol/domain/port as the url you request the JSON from.

Comment: @SamBronson It's also possible that your server already supports JSONP and there's a problem with your request. Why are you using `jsonp: false`?

Comment: A bad idea could be to define the data type as 'text', and then make your own parsing. Or just change to JSON.

Comment: Well, since I can't edit the api and make it accept CORS I simply gave up and defined all as text. :( But still thanks for your help.